# .NET 1 digit rounding of double type behaves differently for large number than numbers less than 1

Tags: c#, .net, double, rounding

`Math.Round(1111_1111_1111_1111.5, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` returns **1111111111111111.6** but I was expecting **1111111111111111.5**

whereas `Math.Round(0.5, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` returns **0.5**

What is the explanation for this behavior? thanks!

Comment: This may fall under this open issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1643